# How to stop services for running in AWS after budget is reached?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cost-explorer

1. I was wondering is it possible to set up a budget for a user eg. if i'm part of organisation and i want only resources i created to monitor and be notified about?
2. My understanding is that if i set up a budget, I'll only be notified in case the budget is reached, but it will not stop resources to run further and generate costs. Is this correct and can it be changed?

Comment: 1. No; 2. Yes, but unfortunately it can not be changed.

Answer (score 2):

AWS does not keep track of "only resources I created". Resources are associated with an AWS Account, not an AWS User. You would need to **tag** all relevant resources with the user who created the resource to be able to identify such 'owners' of resources.

You can create an Alarm based on a budget, and the Alarm could trigger an AWS Lambda function. You could then write code for the Lambda function that turns off / deletes resources based upon their tags.

Please note that some services can be **stopped** to save money and later restarted (eg Amazon EC2 instances, Amazon RDS databases), while some resources can only be **deleted** to stop the charges (eg NAT Gateway, storage in Amazon S3).